# Xcode : NSSortDescriptor custom sorting

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have a fetchedResultsController which need to get instructions as stated in NSMutable array listOfInstructions. This works fine.

However, i want the sort order of fetching to be the same as order of instructions in listOfInstructions. How do i change my sortDescriptor for this ? 
I looked at selector and comparator, and could not find an easy solutions out.

```
 // Define a predicate to get only specific list from DB
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"instructions IN %@",listOfInstructions];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [
                                        [NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                        initWithKey:@"instructions" 
                                        ascending:YES
                                        ];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```